# Restricted character set with regex

Tags: php, regex

When any user creates or edits the company name, I want to make sure it contains only these characters:

- alphanumeric (A-Z, a-z, 0-9)
- , . ? ! @ & # ' ~ * _ - ; +  and space

How to enforce this with a regular expression??

Comment: Do you mean it can only contain those characters?

Comment: Yes, i want to make it contain only those characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
$regEx = '/[^A-Za-z0-9,.?@&!#\'~* _-;+]/'
```

The key is to use a ^ after [
This negates the character list. Therefore any character that does not meet your criterias will be found.

You can use that for example like that

```
if (preg_match($regEx, $input)) {
    throw new Exception('invalid character');
}
```

Comment: You need to escape your single quote, otherwise PHP will stop parsing the string and start complaining about the `~*...` that comes after it.